# How to bind a ComboBox's items to a property of another list's items?

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have a simple `User` class that contains two properties :

```
public class User {
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final StringProperty firstName;

    public User() {
        lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    }

    public User(
            String lastName,
            String firstName
    ) {
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }

    public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName.set(firstName); }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName.set(lastName); }
}
```

I created a window with a `ComboBox` that contains `User` items :

```
public class WindowController {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<User> usersComboBox;

    public void setUserList(ObservableList<User> userList) { }
}
```

I want `setUserList` to bind `userList` to the `usersComboBox`, such that the `ComboBox`'s items are `u.firstName.get() + " " + u.lastName.get()` for each `u` in `userList`. The `ComboBox` must refresh its items every time a `User` is added, removed, or modified in the `userList`.

I've read about binding in JavaFX, but I can't find how to do that. What is the recommended way?

Comment: you don't need to bind anything: simply set userlist (with extractor if "modified" means changes to properties of user) as items to the combo and install a custom cellfactory (or a standard configured with a converter). Anyway, please please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: did you read the help page? if so, why don't you provide an mcve as described? really expect _me_ to write it for _you_? maybe, once hell freezes over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i've understood you correctly.

If so, i do have some example code for you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    private Scene szene = new Scene(root);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();

        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        ObservableList<User> userList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        userList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<?> change)
            {
                comboBox.getItems().clear();
                for(User u : userList)
                {
                    comboBox.getItems().add(u.getName());
                }
            }
        });

        userList.add(new User("Max", "Mustermann"));
        userList.add(new User("Adam", "Sandler"));
        userList.add(new User("Jan", "Boehmermann"));

        root.setCenter(comboBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(szene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can simply instantiate a List and hand it over to FXCollections.observableList(). Then add a ListChangeListener to the ObservableList which updates the ComboBox on change (obviously).

Keep in mind that you have to clear the ObservableList before adding each element to prevent doublings. Don't add elements to the ArrayList, or keep in mind that changes to the ArrayList will NOT trigger the ListChangeListener of the ObservableList!

Comment: hmm ... why would you listen to userList and manually update the combo's items? Simply set userList (with an extractor on first/last name) as the combo's items and install a custom cellFactory for display as needed. And what is list for? you don't need it ..